# Show that $(0,0)$ is not a local minimum of $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Show, that $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)$ reaches it's minimum at $M(0,0)$
>   for $f(t\cos\alpha,t\sin\alpha)$, but $M$ is NOT a local minimum
>   point.

Seemed to be an easy one, but I couldn't handle it.
We have.
$f(t)=(t\sin\alpha-t^2\cos^2\alpha)(t\sin\alpha-2t^2\cos^2\alpha)$ for any fixed $\alpha$
$f'(t)=8t^3\cos^4\alpha-9t^2\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha+2t\sin^2\alpha=0$
$t_0=0$ is a root  for $f'$, and $f'(0)=0$, however it has 2 more roots since $D>0$
$f''(t_0)=24t_0^2\cos^4\alpha-18t_0\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha+2sin^2\alpha=2sin^2\alpha>0$
so $t_0$ is a minimum. part 1 done.

$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x(4x^2-3y)=0 \\ 
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y-3x^2=0
\end{cases}
$$
solution is again $M(0,0)$
$$\frac{\partial^2 f(M)}{\partial x^2}=24x^2-6y=0,\frac{\partial^2 f(M)}{\partial y^2}=2,\frac{\partial^2 f(M)}{\partial x \partial y}=-6x=0$$
$$\Delta  = \begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 f(M)}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f(M)}{\partial x \partial y} \\ 
\frac{\partial^2 f(M)}{\partial x \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 f(M)}{\partial y^2}
\end{vmatrix}=0$$
I've got the determinant is zero for the particular point,
and here I reached to dead end, I have no idea how to continue/conclude, please help me to finish this one. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every neighbourhood of the origin contains points $(x,y)$ for which $f(x,y)>0$ and other points $(s,t)$ for which $f(s,t)<0$, so $(0,0)$ cannot be a local minimum.

Comment: I see this test is inconclusive, when $\Delta=0$, that's what confuses me

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer.

Comment: It seems, my whole work is useless, so you are saying I could have just used the definition of local minimum? then I would need to find an example

Comment: I would expect that in problems involving "local minimum" the definition of "local minimum" could be useful. And no, your work is not useless, because you proved the first part. However, you could have avoided the entire first and second derivative analysis of $f(x,y)$, and just notice that if $0<y<x^2<2x^2$ then $f(x,y)>0$, whereas if $x^2<y<2x^2$ then $f(x,y)<0$. So, technically yes, you would have to find an example (I just did), but that seems to me much easier than what you did, which didn't solve the problem.

Comment: allright, now everything is clear, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Approach the origin along the curve $y=\frac{3}{2}x^2$.  For points along this curve the origin is a local maximum, so the origin can't be a local minimum.